# NodeJS Azure Website returns 405 on HTTP POST

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I provisioned an Azure Website and put an express (nodejs) application on it. The website does not have any special configuration to it, I simply provisioned it and enabled node 0.12.0 in the configuration.

I have an app.post method within the express app, which receives an html form from the browser. However, upon trying to submit this form to the express server, the server returns a 405 Method not Allowed error.

I am suspecting something in IIS is triggering this error, but I have not been able to find a solution. My web.config file allows all verbs for the nodejs app, as shown here:

```
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>          
          <handlers>
               <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
```

Comment: Did you create that web.config file yourself or did Azure Web Apps auto-generate it for you?

Comment: @ZainRizvi It was created by Azure itself, I have not touched it. Yet if I am getting this 405, which I am not configuring anywhere in my express app, then I suspect this error is coming from web.config or somewhere within iis.

Comment: Just to make sure the problem is IIS, does the request work if you're testing on your local machine?

Comment: @zainrizvi yes, if I run the same app on a Linux box by executing node app.js, the POST works without issues

Comment: Can you paste your entire web.config file?

Comment: Try out the instructions on this page and see if it helps you out: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/12/07/Configuring-IIS-verbs-for-ASPNET-Web-API-on-Windows-Azure-Websites-and-elsewhere.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try first removing any existing handlers and then adding the new handler:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="iisnode" />
  <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Just tried add that remove node, same problem, my POST gets a 405 reply

Answer (score 0):

Working answer proposed on [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3ee79852-3192-489e-8ee3-176238b5ad55/nodejs-azure-website-returns-405-on-http-post?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview):

Comment out this line from the web.config file:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
```